# Input CSV to Custom NER Model in SpaCy

Tags: python, machine-learning, spacy

very new to ML and Python and appreciate any help for this issue. I've trained an NER model using Prodigy (based on en_core_web_lg) and saved the model to my virtual environment:

[image: My Model]

I'm on Windows 10 with CONDA/VSCODE, SpaCy 2.x environment and I'm now trying to load a comma delimited CSV file that looks like this:

[image]

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg", disable=["ner"]) #remove NER of base model
print(nlp.pipe_names) #check to see if removed
nlp_entity = spacy.load("tmp_model", vocab=nlp.vocab) #load my tmp model
nlp.add_pipe(nlp_entity.get_pipe("ner")) #add back NER
print(nlp.pipe_names) #check to see if it was added back
nlp.to_disk("./tmp_model2") #save combo as a new model name

nlp=spacy.load("tmp_model2") #load new model
doc=nlp("Paragraph Text Here") #test the model with this text to see if its working
print(doc.text)
for ent in doc.ents: #for all entities in doc
     print(ent.label_, ent.text) #get the label and text
```

From here, this is where I get stuck. I said to myself, I can just read in the CSV file like this:

```
input = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv') #read in CSV via Pandas
doc=nlp(input['Text']) #look for "Text" column in the CSV file and run the model for each row
for ent in doc.ents:
     print(ent.label_, ent.text)
```

**TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got Series)**

Again very very new to Python, but I think I need to convert the Pandas dataframe into a string? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlp` accepts strings as inputs, you are correct.

If you want to use it on one paragraph, you can do it like this:

`doc=nlp(input['Text'].values[0])`

Where `0` is a number of the paragraph.

Comment: Thank you, but how would I loop through all the rows of the "Text" column?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of Andrey's post, I was able to figure out the appropriate syntax to spit out all rows.

```
input = pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv')
row_nums = len(input.index)
print("Number of rows is: ", len(input.index))
for x in range (0,row_nums):
    print(x, " LOOP START")
    doc=nlp(input['Text'].values[x])
    print(doc.text)
    for ent in doc2.ents:
        print(ent.label_, ent.text)
```

The next step is for me to figure out how to push this back out to a CSV file!